# Why is assert a macro and not a function?

Tags: c, assert, c-preprocessor

My lecturer has asked me that in class, and I was wondering why is it a macro instead of a function?

Comment: When implementing my own assertions i always do it as macros because i want to be able to return from the asserting function, not only from the assert function. A macro can do something and have the calling function return - success!

Comment: @Martin: ... and a rather questionable programming practice. A macro that hides a jump statement?

Comment: @AndreyT: That would be questionable indeed.  So the name of the macro shouldn't *hide* the jump.  I've used such macros before, they can be quite clear if named well.

Comment: As far a I can tell the question and all the answers apply equally to C++ as well.

Comment: I find the [g_return](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Warnings-and-Assertions.html#g-return-if-fail) family of macros defined by `GLib` a good example of those quite explicitly named assertions.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The simple explanation would be that the standard requires `assert` to be a macro, if we look at the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)(*as far as I can tell the sections are the same in [draft C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) as well*) section `7.2` *Diagnostics*  paragraph *2* says:

> The assert macro shall be implemented as a macro, not as an actual
>   function. If the macro definition is suppressed in order to access an
>   actual function, the behavior is undefined.

Why does it require this, the rationale given in [Rationale for International Standard—Programming Languages—C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) is:

> It can be difficult or impossible to make assert a true function, so it is restricted to macro
>   form.

which is not very informative, but we can see from other requirements why. Going back to section `7.2` paragraph *1* says:

> [...]If NDEBUG is defined as a macro name at the point in the source file
>   where  is included, the assert macro is defined simply as
>
> ```
> #define assert(ignore) ((void)0)
> ```
>
> The assert macro is redefined according to the current state of NDEBUG
>   each time that  is included.

This is important since it allows us an easy way to turn off assertions in release mode where you may want to take the cost of potentially expensive checks.

and the second important requirement is that it is required to use the macros `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`  and `__func__`, which is covered in section `7.2.1.1` *The assert macro* which says:

> [...] the assert macro writes information about the particular call
>   that failed [...] the latter are respectively the values of the
>   preprocessing macros __FILE_ _ and __LINE_ _ and of the identifier
>   __func_ _) on the standard error stream in an implementation-defined format.<sup>165)</sup> It then calls the abort function.

where footnote `165` says:

> The message written might be of the form:
>
> ```
> Assertion failed: expression, function abc, file xyz, line nnn.
> ```

Having it as a macro allows the macros `__FILE__` etc... to be evaluated in the proper location and as Joachim points out being a macro allows it to insert the original *expression* in the message it generates.

The draft C++ standard requires that the contents of the `cassert` header are the same as the `assert.h` header from Standrd C library:

> The contents are the same as the Standard C library header .
>
> > See also: ISO C 7.2.

**Why (void)0?**

Why use `(void)0` as opposed to some other expression that does nothing? We can come up with a few reasons, first this is how the assert synopsis looks in section `7.2.1.1`:

```
void assert(scalar expression);
```

and it says (*emphasis mine*):

> The assert macro puts diagnostic tests into programs; it **expands to a void expression.**

the expression `(void)0` is consistent with the need to end up with a *void expression*.

Assuming we did not have that requirement, other possible expressions could have undesirable effects such as allowing uses of `assert` in release mode that would not be allowed in debug mode for example using [plain `0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002719/casting-0-to-void) would allow us to use `assert` in an assignment and when used correctly would likely generate an `expression result unused` warning. As for using a *compound statement* as a comment suggests, we can see from [C multi-line macro: do/while(0) vs scope block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1067238/1708801) that they an have undesirable effects in some cases.

Comment: I think another big reason is because a function would require the expression to have a particular type, but that type has to be compatible with any other type (technically, it has to be compatible with whatever may appear in an `if`/`while` statement)

Comment: @Drew McGowen: In C99 it would simply have a parameter of type `_Bool` as that "particular type". Any scalar type is implicitly convertible to `_Bool`.

Answer (score 44):

1. It allows capturing the file (through `__FILE__`) and line number (through `__LINE__`)
2. It allows the `assert` to be substituted for a valid expression which does nothing (i.e. `((void)0)`) when building in release mode

Comment: To be precise, by `((void)0)`.

Comment: Also, it also allows the actual expression to be expressed as a string in the error message.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: When performing textual substitution (which is all the preprocessor does) the empty string **is** nothing.

Comment: @RobertAllanHenniganLeahy: What he is saying. Is that assert (as per the standard) is not replaced by the empty string, but with the string `((void)0)` when NDEBUG is defined.

Comment: `assert` is required to be a valid *expression* at all times. "Empty string" is not a valid expression, which is why `assert` cannot be replaced by an empty string. I can use `assert` like this: `a = (assert(b > 0), b)`. This is perfectly valid expression. If `assert` suddenly became an empty string, this expression would become invalid.

Comment: You all misunderstood. What Joachim meat was that `assert(1==2)` can print a message like "Assertion failed: 1==2". That's not possible unless it's a macro.

Answer (score 13):

This macro is disabled if, at the moment of including , a macro with the name NDEBUG has already been defined. This allows for a coder to include as many assert calls as needed in a source code while debugging the program and then disable all of them for the production version by simply including a line like:

```
#define NDEBUG
```

at the beginning of its code, before the inclusion of `<assert.h>`.

**Therefore, this macro is designed to capture programming errors, not user or run-time errors, since it is generally disabled after a program exits its debugging phase.**

---

Making it as function will increase some function calls and you can not control all such asserts in release mode.

If you use function then `_FILE__`, `__LINE__` and `__func__` will give the value of that assert function's code. Not that calling line or calling function's line.

Comment: Making it as function will increase some function calls and you can not control all such asserts in release mode.

Answer (score 13):

Some assertions can be expensive to call. You've just written a high performance matrix inversion routine, and you add a sanity check

```
assert(is_identity(matrix * inverse))
```

to the end. Well, your matrices are pretty big, and if `assert` is a function, it would take a lot of time to do the computation before passing it into assert. Time you really don't want to spend if you're not doing debugging.

Or maybe the assertion is relatively cheap, but it's contained in a very short function that will get called in an inner loop. Or other similar circumstances.

By making `assert` a macro instead, you can eliminate the calculation entirely when assertions are turned off.

Comment: Apple's swift tackles this problem of having to resolve arguments before calling the function a bit but they don't have a precompiler, after all.

Comment: @WorldSEnder I had the exact thought. It's a clever solution and they even used it for &&, ||, and so on. Auto-closures FTW! :-p

Answer (score 2):

> Why is assert a macro and not a function?

Because it should compiled in **DEBUG** mode and should not compiled in **RELEASE** mode.